# What happens if memory for a format string is shared with one of the arguments of printf?

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior, format-string, restrict-qualifier

According to the C Standard, the signature of `printf()` is:

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

As I understand, the meaning of the `restrict` is that `format` will be the only reference to the pointed-to data within the lifetime of the pointer. This enables optimizations for reasons I do not fully grasp. But does this mean that undefined behavior is invoked if I reuse memory for the format string as an argument? Even though, as far as I can tell, the format string is not required to be a string literal?

```
static const char str[] = "%sHello\n";
printf(str, str + 2); // Hello\nHello\n or UB?
```

I know the implementation might reuse the memory for identical or identically-ending string literals:

```
"foo" + 1 == "oo"; // Might be true
```

Does that mean that the following:

```
printf("%sHello\n", "Hello\n");
```

Might behave in a nonsensical manner if an implementation makes both string literals share memory, thus violating the `restrict` constraint?

Comment: Don't forget that both the behavior of `restrict` and the allocation of string constants are up to the implementation of the compiler. The compiler that would both allocate both strings as in your example to the same memory *and* will consider it as a violation of `restrict` is a buggy compiler.

Comment: In the ordinary course of events, there won't be a problem.  However, as the accepted answer to the duplicate question points out, the `%n` modifier modifies one of the arguments to `printf()`, and that pointer must not violate the `restrict` modifier.  Note that the "safe" I/O functions such as [`fprintf_s()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.1) and its relatives prohibit the use of `%n`, and this is one of the reasons why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand, the meaning of the `restrict` is that `format` will be the only reference to the pointed-to data within the lifetime of the pointer.

Not quite. It means that if the `format` string<sup>1</sup> is modified by any means (through `format` or otherwise), then `printf` must access it only through other expressions based on `format` (and therefore the caller must not pass another argument that would result in `printf` accessing the format string through that argument), per C 2018 6.7.3.1. If nothing in the format string is going to be modified during the `printf` call, it does not matter what other pointers to it there are.

I think the only way this can matter is if you use the `n` conversion specifier, which says the corresponding argument is a pointer to a signed integer into which is written the number of character written to the output stream so far by this call to `printf`. So, if the `format` were not `restrict-qualified` you could write these two `printf` calls:

```
int n;
memcpy(&n, "x%n", 4);
printf((char *) &n, &n);  // Would store 1 in `n`, since “x” had been written.

const char String[] = "Hello, world.\n%n";
int *p = malloc(sizeof String);
memcpy(p, String, sizeof String);
printf(p, p);  // Would store int `14` at `p`.
```

The former would be legal because any object can be read through a character type, which `printf` presumably does in effect. The latter is legal because the effective type of dynamic memory is malleable, so writing to `p` as an `int` after it has been used as a character string is defined.

Obviously, it would be problematic if the `%n` caused a write to memory that `printf` was possibly yet to use for the format string. Again, this is in the context where we assume the string is not qualified with `restrict`. Given that it is, the behavior of using `%n` in this way would not be defined.

(`n` can also be used with modifiers, as in `%hhn` to write a `char` instead of an `int`, but this does not affect the above analysis.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Technically, any object *based* on `format`, which is essentially all the elements of the array object that `format` points to (which includes earlier elements in the array if `format` points into the middle of an array).

Comment: If for whatever reason, `format` points to memory that `printf` could modify, that is the only restriction that the `restrict` imposes. That is how I understand it now.

Comment: I don't think it's plausible that `restrict` was supposed to disallow the use of unrelated pointers to operate on disjoint parts of the same object.  The ability of functions like `memcpy` to copy one element of an array to another element *of the same array* has so far as I am aware never been even remotely questioned.

Comment: @supercat: This answer does not say that it does. The footnote mentions that other elements of an array that `format` points into would be based on `format`, but that is a footnote to an “if” clause, so it would apply only if `printf` accessed those elements.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Your footnote implies that if any portion of an object (including a structure or a multi-dimensional array object) is accessed using the format string, no part of that object may be modified during the execution of the function.  The notion of "based upon" is very is important, but has nothing to do with treating an access to part of an object as though it were an access to the whole thing.

Comment: @supercat: No, it does not. The footnote completes the specification of *based* on to note that any element in the same array as the one into which `format` points would be *based* on `format`. The consequence of that is that if `printf` used `format` to access any such element, the lvalue it used would be an `L` in C 2018 6.7.3.1 4 and would be subject to the requirements of it. Nothing in the footnote or the answer says elements of the array not used by `printf` would be subject to the same requirements or that the entire array as an object itself is subject to them.

Comment: @supercat: `printf` would not have any lvalue for the entire array, so it would not have any lvalue for the array that would be an `L` in C 2018 6.7.3.1 4, even if an lvalue for an array could be said to be used to access the array rather than converted to a pointer which is then used in an lvalue to access the array.